# Separate Inline lists

Tags: html, css, list

I have been trying to separate a list that is already inline with itself, here is the HTML code underneath.

```
<div class="TopNavigation">
    <ul class="Separate">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="index3.html">Tools</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS code.

```
.TopNavigation a {
    color: Black;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.TopNavigation li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.TopNavigation {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

I would like the "Home" to be on the left side of the page and the "Gallery" and "Tools" to be on the right of the page. How do I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assing `float:right` to all, except the first li element of the list:

```css
.TopNavigation a {
    color: Black;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.TopNavigation li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.TopNavigation {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.TopNavigation li:not(:first-of-type) {
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="TopNavigation">
    <ul class="Separate">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="index3.html">Tools</a></li>            
<li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Note, however, that this **changes the visual order of the links that are floated right**.

Answer (score 2):

Align the list items to the right by using `text-align:right` on the parent and the float the first child to the left.

```css
.TopNavigation a {
  color: Black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.Separate {
  text-align: right;
}
.TopNavigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
.TopNavigation li:first-child {
  float: left;
}
.TopNavigation {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="TopNavigation">
  <ul class="Separate">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index3.html">Tools</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

divide the list into two and align the accordingly

```css
.TopNavigation {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.TopNavigation a {
  color: Black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.TopNavigation li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.TopNavigation .left {
  float: left;
}
.TopNavigation .right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="TopNavigation">
  <ul class="left">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="right">
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="index3.html">Tools</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```